# umbraco: get USER properties, NOT member properties in XSLT

Tags: xslt, umbraco, umbraco-blog

Here's my scenario:

1. Added an `Author Picker` to the default `umbBlogPost` (from the blog4umbraco package) which gives me access to the author's id in an XSLT macro
2. The `Author Picker` is pulling up a list of umbraco **users**, not members
3. I want to the display the author's username in xslt output

I've tried several different ways based on Google searches which all seem to be using the Membership API, such as `umbraco.libary:GetMember` and `umbraco.library:GetMemberName` which is not working, again, as I am dealing with umbraco users, not members. There **doesn't appear to be** any user equivalent methods, i.e., `umbraco.libary:GetUser` or `umbraco.library:GetUserName`.

Does anyone know how I can get user properties in an xslt macro? I am using version 4.7.2. Also, while I'm currently working with xslt, if this can be done with a Razor macro (if supported in 4.7.2?) I am open to seeing this approach as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by writing a Razor macro. The key was to add `@using umbraco.BusinessLogic;` at the beginning of the macro. This namespace provides the API required to get user data as opposed to member data.

For anyone interested, here's the macro I wrote:

```
@using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext


<div>
  <h1>
    From Our Blog
  </h1>
  <ul>
  @foreach(var i in @Model.AncestorOrSelf("umbHomepage").Descendants("umbBlogPost").OrderBy("PostDate desc").Take(5))
  {
    <li>
      <p>
        <a href="@i.NiceUrl" title="@i.Name">@i.Name</a><br />
        by <a href="#">@umbraco.BusinessLogic.User.GetUser(Int32.Parse(i.blogAuthor)).Name</a> on @i.PostDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")
      </p>
    </li>
  }
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look directly in the XML that the XSLTs run off (`~/App_Data/umbraco.config`), I found the following attributes:

```xml
<Site 
     writerID="0" 
     creatorID="0" 
     writerName="John Smith"
     creatorName="John Smith" 
     />
```

So you should be able to reference those in the XSLT with the following:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/@writerName" />
```

If you need the other properties of the user, you'll probably need to write your own library, which could then be accessed by the XSLT files. Just look at how `umbraco.library` is included at the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd found the two properties you're referencing but my situation is a bit different as I've added a custom property to the document of type `Author Picker` so that the writer can specify the author. I think I've solved the problem using a Razor macro and will post as an answer after verifying.

Comment: Ahh, you did mention that in your question. Sorry, I read the question, went to make a coffee and came back to answer forgetting that significant detail. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the blog package to suggest otherwise. Perhaps they've included a library already just waiting to be included, perhaps they've included the info you need in child nodes in the XML. Either way, sounds like you found an alternative. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Ucomponents provides an XSLT solution

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$currentPage/bodyAuthor != ''">
    <xsl:value-of select="ucomponents.cms:GetUserName($currentPage/bodyAuthor)"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/@writerName" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```